# Could not find the type 'tSQLt.Private'

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsqlt

I have installed tSQLt with CLR permissions Off. I am not sure how it got installed. I see some stored procedure of class tSQLt. Now I am trying to re-install it by cleaning tSQLt, but could not able to do it.

When I run `tSQLt.Uninstall` it gives the below message

```
EXEC tSQLt.Uninstall
Msg 218, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Uninstall, Line 5
Could not find the type 'tSQLt.Private'. Either it does not exist or you do not have the necessary permission.
```

No I have ran the `tSQLt.cleanup` It give the following error.

```
Msg 3729, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Cannot drop schema 'tSQLt' because it is being referenced by object 'NullTestResultFormatter'.
```

Can someone help me on this context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't uninstall tSQLt because **tSQLt.Private** type from **tSQLtCLR** assembly does not exists in your case (because you did not enable SQL CLR before installation).

[image]

```
select * from sys.assembly_types where assembly_class = 'tSQLtCLR.tSQLtPrivate'
```

To re/un-install tSQLt in your case you need:

**1.Enable SQL CLR:**

```
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @cmd='ALTER DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(DB_NAME()) + ' SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;';
EXEC(@cmd);
GO
```

**2.Re-install tSQLt** - simply execute sql script from **tSQLt.class.sql** (it drops and recreate all objects if they do exist)

**3.Un-install tSQLt** (if you need)

```
EXEC [tSQLt].[Uninstall]
```